# 'Hyperspace_Cheese_Battle.Program.RocketInSquare(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

```
    static bool RocketInSquare(int X, int Y)
    {

    }
```

As it says in the title, this is the error I am getting and I can't seem to understand what it means, can anyone help me?

Comment: Paste your code also inside this method..

Comment: It means your function does not return anything for a certain code path. Please provide the entire contents of the function.

Comment: just curious, but which part of the error confused you? that is easily one of the *most* easily understood error messages C# can spit out, and knowing how to read them is mandatory for serious C# development...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an obvious coding error

Answer (score 4):

You defined a method that is expected to return a bool value. So the compiler is going to error unless you return a value like so:

```
static bool RocketInSquare(int X, int Y)
{
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay, cheers for the reply.